# SQL export to flat file is running faster than the same export in SSIS in a job

Tags: sql, performance, ssis, export

I have a job that run an SSIS package that exports a whole table (15 G)   ( select * from table) into a flat file.

It takes 3 hrs  for the export to complete - when I do the same using the Export wizard, It take less than  10 mins. So I saved the Export wizard as  SSIS package and ran it through a job

But again it is very slow. I am on SQL 19 and any help  is really appreciated.

Comment: Do both packages write to the exact same location? When you run the Import/Export wizard, are you remoted into the server or are you on you using SSMS from your desktop?

Comment: On the server, from a command line how long does bcp take? `bcp Database.Schema.Table out SomeFile.txt -c -T -S MyServer\Instance`

Comment: both  write to the same location  - an am running on the server not remote

Comment: bcp is fast  same like the Wizard

Comment: @billinkc can you clarify a different delimiter (other than tab say |)?

Comment: @KeithL Yeah [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) supports different field terminators via the `-t` option. When your use case aligns with what BCP offers, it's ridiculously good and fast at getting data into and out of the database.

Comment: So, both packages run on the server (Wizard or job) writing to the same location so they both have to deal with the same CPU/memory/disk contention. The next most likely variable then is table contention - does a process have the table locked for some reason when the job runs that is not present when the interactive run takes place. If the job consistently takes that long, create a parallel job that [logs sp_whoisactive to a table](https://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/) and see what all the package is waiting on.

Comment: the wait was always Aysnc_network_IO   , but again am not seeing that when running from the wizard

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing  `defaultBufferMaxRows` to an extremely large number

`DefaultBufferSize` : default is 10MB, max possible 2^31-1 bytes

`DefaultBufferMaxRows` : default is 10000

you can set `AutoAdjustBufferSize` so that `DefaultBufferSize` is automatically calculated based on `DefaultBufferMaxRows`

See other performance troubleshooting ideas here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-flow-performance-features?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

looks like when you change the package to run as 32bit instead  of 64 the process runs the way we expected

thank you all for your help